# Convert from text(char(50)) to datetime

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

I'm trying to convert my text column to a datetime. I've tried several things but i keep getting errors. The steps I tried so far:

```
Convert(datetime, mydate, 103)
```

The error it gives after performing this query in my system:
'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime'
So I searched on the internet and found several solutions which I tried.

```
Convert(datetime, convert(char(8), mydate)
```

and

```
Cast(cast(mydate as char(8)) as datetime)
```

The error it gives me after performing these queries: 'conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string' So I searched for more possible solutions and tried this:

```
Convert(datetime, convert(char(8), mydate),103)
```

But this still gives me the same error. I really run out of solutions right now. Does any of you guys maybe know how to fix this problem?

Kind regards and thanks in advance

Here is some sample data:

```
+----+------------+
| ID |   MyDate   |
+----+------------+
| 1  |  20170120  |
+----+------------+
| 2  |  19940101  |
+----+------------+
| 3  |  20001220  |
+----+------------+
| 4  |  20171101  |
+----+------------+
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: None of those conversions will work if you use the *wrong* format. What do the values look like? Could there be mixed MM/DD and DD/MM values? If there are, you can't convert the text with a single command. You'll have to discover *somehow* what format was used for each entry

Comment: please post your query! Im sure there is something wrong with the type or declaration!

Comment: @Tito there's no reason to assume problems with the type or declaration. `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime'` wouldn't be thrown in this case. It's *far* more likely that the *text* doesn't match the format

Comment: I would not expect your error ("'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime' ") on a conversion from a *string* to a *datetime*.  You might get something like this:  "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think your right!

Comment: I've added some simple sample data, this is what it looks like

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely with formatting.  Do you have an example of the string you're trying to convert to a datetime?

I would advise referring to the "style" parameter in the documentation to ensure it matches the string format that you're passing into the CONVERT function.  If you can provide a sample string it will be easier to suggest a working example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

@miltenburger, I am guessing that @mydate has been stored as integer. That is why it throws the error:
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime

What you need to do is to convert it to varchar first before converting to datetime.

See the mockup below:

```
DECLARE @mydate INT =20181001


SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(@mydate as VARCHAR(20)), 103)
```

Comment: I am right. It has been stored as integer. This is the solution. Cast to VARCHAR first and then convert.

Comment: I've tried this one, now i'm getting the out of range values error, so i'm gonna try to solve this....

Comment: I think we are very close. Check the database dateformat. See another solution below. It is possible you have set your database default dateformat. verify that all of date is in 'yyyymmdd'. It is possible some odd entries are in there.

Comment: Working on it, will come back on this

Comment: I think I found the problem in my dataset. There are a few different ways they've put the data in:

20150117

But also: 2015-01-17

Is there a way of converting both these different types of varchar to a date?

Comment: you can easily remove the '-', using the replace fuction like this: SELECT REPLACE('2015-01-17','-',''). One thing this shows, is that the column datatype is not INT, but rather varchar/nvarchar. Can you recheck again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the database Implied DATEFORMAT set by language

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english

SELECT CAST('2018-02-25' AS datetime)

SET LANGUAGE british

SELECT CAST('2018-02-25' AS datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong format

```
select convert(datetime, '20000113', 112)
```